# Google Maps Places Autocomplete - Not Returning Street Numbers?

Tags: json, google-places-api

I'm looking to build a pretty basic address search functionality inside of my iOS app. I'm using Google Places Autocomplete to query for results based on users input, like below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=shoppers@&radius=160934&location=50.445210,-104.618896&components=country:ca&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The results I'm getting back are far too vague to be of practical use. Below is one example, where all I get is the name of the business and the street that it is on. Problem being, there are three different locations for this business on the same street, so how would the user be able to figure out which one they're selecting without being provided a street number?

```
{
         "description" : "Shoppers Drug Mart, Albert Street, Regina, SK, Canada",
         "id" : "94065830c922a4239ece26102fb3439fa2f2e155",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 8,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ4XzAGbCgHlMRGSFBsEbyfCE",
         "reference" : "ChIJ4XzAGbCgHlMRGSFBsEbyfCE",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Shoppers Drug Mart",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 8,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Albert Street, Regina, SK, Canada"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Shoppers Drug Mart"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "Albert Street"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 35,
               "value" : "Regina"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 43,
               "value" : "SK"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 47,
               "value" : "Canada"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "pharmacy", "health", "point_of_interest", "store", "establishment" ]
      },
```

Comment: Why not do a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) right away if you already have a complete or partially complete search term? Doing a nearby search or text search should work with the input "shoppers".

Answer (score 5):

Places Autocomplete is not designed to return detailed address information. It is designed to return predictions based on your input. You then have to use the Place ID that gets returned and make a Place Details request using it to get a response that includes address information, etc.

Using the first result from your autocomplete request, I can form a Place Details request like:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ4XzAGbCgHlMRGSFBsEbyfCE&key=YOUR_API_KEY
That will give the information you desire.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id#example-using-the-places-api

Comment: Okay - that seems incredibly inefficient and I was hoping there was a better way. Thank you